# Xamarin Forms Layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im building a auditing mobile application initially for android and will also be on iOS in future.

What the best approach when using Xamarin.Forms to create a dynamic question/answer form. I want to control this from a template held on a server so i can easily add/remove questions.

Each Item will have a question, Answer (this could be text, Yes/No, date picker etc..) you will have a option to add a comment to a question and also upload multiple images to the question.

What is the best way to:

1, Render the controls onto the layout using code behind or XAML
2, what would you use to lay these out (stack panel?)
3, when the user submits the form how would you get the values from the controls

[Wireframe of the example Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP1G1.png)

Comment: Please read this and improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Question 1 is far too vague. What objects are you referring to? Question 2 - Yes, use StackLayout. Question 3 is also too vague. What do you mean by "get the data"? Which data?

Answer (score 0):

Your question's a little light on specifics, so all I can offer are general recommendations.

If the intent is to have a set of fields that are composed at runtime (as opposed to a predefined layout), your simplest path will be to compose it using codebehind.

StackLayout is a simple linear layout, and is well-suited to most data-entry applications. The general pattern I would recommend is Label/Data Entry, repeat as needed.

There are a number of ways to get the data back out of the controls, but the simplest possible way would be to maintain a tree that maps your data fields to UI elements and inject/extract data using that tree.

Now, there are ways to dynamically compose the XAML as well as use MVVM in a dynamic manner (see [Daniel Cazzulino's post](http://www.cazzulino.com/dynamic-forms.html) which is really cool stuff!), but for a simple application that may be more complexity than you need.